# How to analyze the growth of the following code?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, analysis

I already know that the worst case complexity is N, and the best case is Mlog(M) but I just don't see how. Can anybody explain to me why this is the case and what different inputs would cause each case?

```
public static Iterable<Integer> topM(int[] a, int M){
int N = a.length;
MinPQ<Integer> pq = new MinPQ<Integer>(M+1);
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    if(pq.size() < M)
        pq.insert(a[i]);
    if(pq.min() <= a[i]){
        pq.insert(a[i]);
        pq.delMin();
    }
}
return pq;
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't this be `else if`, instead of `if` for the second `if`?

Comment: The best case of Mlog(M) doesn't seem right.  The program contains a loop that has O(N) complexity, so at best the complexity of the whole program must be something multiplied by N.

Comment: It looks to me like the best case is O(N) and the worst is O(Nlog(N)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is `O(Nlog(M))`. The worst case is when the array is sorted in a ascending order, in this case each element is inserted to the queue.
The best case is when the array is sorted in a descending order, in this case only the first M elements are inserted. The complexity in the best case is `O(N+Mlog(M))`.
p.s. the first comment is correct, the second `if` should be `else if`.